# Update jsonb list item in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am try to update key name of 1 field in my `jsonb` list.

**Initial data**

```
select jsonb_array_elements(status_history) from deals;
>>> [{"date": "2020-10-02T12:05:02.728691", "state": "gathering_info"}, {"date": "2020-10-08T10:15:20.798500", "state": "archived"}, {"date": "2020-10-08T10:43:17.651033", "state": "gathering_info"}]
>>> ...
```

I can retrieve each element with this function

```
select jsonb_array_elements(status_history) from deals;

>>> {"date": "2020-10-02T11:51:55.624263", "state": "gathering_info"}
```

I want to update `state` key to be `status` and I try to do this

```
update deals set elem=elem & {'status': elem->'state'} from (select jsonb_array_elements(status_history) from deals) elem;
update deals set elem->'status' = elem->'state' from (select jsonb_array_elements(status_history) from deals) elem;
```

But this is not work. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the array while keeping track of the position of each object, change the key name in each individual element using operators `-` and `||`, then reaggregate. Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, you could phrase this as:

```
update deals d
set status_history = d1.status_history
from (
    select d.id, 
        json_agg(
            x.obj - 'state' || jsonb_build_object('status', x.obj -> 'state')
            order by x.n
        ) as status_history
    )
    from deals d
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.status_history) with ordinality as x(obj, n)
    group by d.id
) d1
where d1.id = d.id
```